# theorems and definitions boxes (numbering should be chapter-wise)

Tags: numbering, theorems, tcolorbox, books

I want to write both the **theorems and definitions** (numbering should be chapter-wise, like 2.1, 2.2 etc) in the form of the attached jpg file. [image]

EDIT:

> In the upper box only the title will come and within the box, the theorem/definition number will come. What to do?

I get a code in internet. I don't know how to modify it. Please help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}{
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshifttext=-1mm
  },
  colback=white,
  colframe=blue!75!black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  boxed title style={
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!75!black,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
  } 
}{thm}
\newtcbtheorem[no counter]{Proof}{Proof}{
  enhanced,
  sharp corners,
  attach boxed title to top left={
    yshifttext=-1mm
  },
  colback=white,
  colframe=blue!25,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  coltitle=black,
  boxed title style={
    sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!25,
    colframe=blue!25,
  } 
}{prf}

\begin{document}
\begin{Theorem}{}{fermat}
  No three positive integers \(a\), \(b\) and \(c\) satisfy the equation \(a^{n}
  + b^{n} = c^{n}\) for any integer greater than two.
\end{Theorem}
\begin{Proof}{Theorem \ref{thm:fermat}}{}
  The proof is easy, but too large to fit in this box.
\end{Proof}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2: Only the problem is in setting counter. Theorem should come 1.1, 1.2 ... and definition should come same as 1.1, 1.2 ....**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\tcbset{theostyle/.style={
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    attach boxed title to top left={
      xshift=-1mm,
      yshift=-4mm,
      yshifttext=-1mm
    },
    top=1.5ex,
    colback=white,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    boxed title style={
      sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!75!black,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
  } 
}}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{Theorem}{Theorem}{%
  theostyle
}{thm}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{Definition}{Definition}{%
  theostyle
}{def}
\newenvironment{myTheorem}[2]{ \begin{Theorem}[adjusted title=#1]{}{#2} 
  \textbf{Theorem \thetcbcounter.} }{\end{Theorem}}
\newenvironment{myDefinition}[2]{ \begin{Theorem}[adjusted title=#1]{}{#2} 
  \textbf{Definition \thetcbcounter.} }{\end{Theorem}}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo chapter}

\begin{myDefinition}{ggggggggg}{ReadingTheManual}
  Reading the manual helps ;-)
\end{myDefinition}

\begin{myTheorem}{fffff}{fermat}
  No three positive integers \(a\), \(b\) and \(c\) satisfy the equation \(a^{n}
  + b^{n} = c^{n}\) for any integer greater than two.
\end{myTheorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Numbering within `chapters` when using `article` class? ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{Theorem}{}{
        enhanced,
        sharp corners,
        attach boxed title to top left={
            xshift=-1mm,
            yshift=-5mm,
            yshifttext=-1mm
        },
        top=1.5em,
        colback=white,
        colframe=blue!75!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        boxed title style={
            sharp corners,
            size=small,
            colback=blue!75!black,
            colframe=blue!75!black,
        } 
    }{thm}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{Definition}{}{
        enhanced,
        sharp corners,
        attach boxed title to top left={
            xshift=-1mm,
            yshift=-5mm,
            yshifttext=-1mm
        },
        top=1.5em,
        colback=white,
        colframe=blue!75!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        boxed title style={
            sharp corners,
            size=small,
            colback=blue!75!black,
            colframe=blue!75!black,
        } 
    }{def}

\newenvironment{myTheorem}[2]{ \begin{Theorem}[adjusted title=#1]{}{#2} 
  \textbf{Theorem \thetcbcounter.} }{\end{Theorem}}

  \newenvironment{myDefinition}[2]{ \begin{Definition}[adjusted title=#1]{}{#2} 
  \textbf{Definition \thetcbcounter.} }{\end{Definition}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\begin{myTheorem}{Fermats Last Theorem}{thm:FermatsLastTheorem}
    No three positive integers \(a\), \(b\) and \(c\) satisfy the equation \(a^{n} + b^{n} = c^{n}\) for any integer greater than two.
\end{myTheorem}
\begin{myDefinition}{Reading the Manual}{def:ReadingTheManual}
  Reading the manual helps ;-)
\end{myDefinition}
\begin{myDefinition}{Definition}{def:Definition}
  A statement of the meaning of a word, phrase, or term, as in a dictionary entry.
\end{myDefinition}
\begin{myTheorem}{Pythagoras Theorem}{thm:PythagorasTheorem}
    In a right angled triangle: the square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the other two sides.
\end{myTheorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is what exactly I want. Only problem is that the Definition which would come 1.1, 1.2 ... be included. Please modify the code to get this in addition.

Comment: I have edited my post above and my modified code has a problem is setting counter in Th and Def

Comment: @user1942348 I included the Definition environment.

Comment: How would you use `\ref{}` now?

Answer (score 9):

Use the `number within=chapter` 'init' option of the `\newtcbtheorem` macro to apply `chapter-wise` counting of theorems defined with this macro. (See sections 5 and 16 of the `tcolorbox` manual for more information on the `init option`.)

The box style can be changed by using the `xshift` and `yshift` keys of `attach boxed title to top left`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\tcbset{theostyle/.style={
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    attach boxed title to top left={
      xshift=-1mm,
      yshift=-4mm,
      yshifttext=-1mm
    },
    top=1.5ex,
    colback=white,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    boxed title style={
      sharp corners,
    size=small,
    colback=blue!75!black,
    colframe=blue!75!black,
  } 
}}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{Theorem}{Theorem}{%
  theostyle
}{thm}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{Definition}{Definition}{%
  theostyle
}{def}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo chapter}

\begin{Definition}{}{ReadingTheManual}
  Reading the manual helps ;-)
\end{Definition}

\begin{Theorem}{}{fermat}
  No three positive integers \(a\), \(b\) and \(c\) satisfy the equation \(a^{n}
  + b^{n} = c^{n}\) for any integer greater than two.
\end{Theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When I run, I am getting error. File shellesc.sty not found and unable to install it. Also I don't need the proof box. I need def box also and modify the box style as I gave it the jpg file.  Please help.

Comment: @user1942348: Well, if you don't need the proof, omit it. The `definition` box can be done in the same way.

Comment: Also How to modify the box style as I gave it the jpg file

Comment: @user1942348: Now it is there. The `shellesc.sty` is just a matter of installation -- there's nothing I can do for that.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. In the upper box only the title will come and within the box, the theorem/definition number will come. What to do?

Comment: @user1942348: I'll take a look later on.

Comment: +1, for your work with `tcolorbox`. Hi.