# Corners for theorems and definitions

Tags: boxes, theorems, rounded-corners

I was wondering if there is any package or a simple snippet I could use to get the kind of corners shown in the picture for theorems and definitions.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Source: MIT Mathematics of Machine Learning course.]

Comment: Yes, such packages exist and they are called tcolorbox and tcolorbox. Just do a google *image* search for `site:tex.stackexchange.com tcolorbox theorem` and click on whatever looks promising. This will give you an idea and also a starting point for a question which is more appreciated.

Comment: @marmot I found some packages like that one but they provide full boxes. I didn't see any example showing isolated corners. Maybe it's possible to do it with the tcolorbox tools, but I have no idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to give you a start. All I did was to look up an answer, I randomly chose [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369739/121799) and cooked it down to

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=chapter]{Theorem}{}{
        enhanced,sharp corners,colback=white,colframe=white,top=-0.5em,
        overlay={%
        \draw[gray!40,line width=3pt] ([yshift=-1cm]frame.north west) 
        |- ++ (1,1) ([yshift=1cm]frame.south east) |- ++ (-1,-1);
        },
    }{thm}

\newenvironment{myTheorem}[1]{\begin{Theorem}{}{#1}\textbf{Theorem:}}{\end{Theorem}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Foo}
\begin{myTheorem}{thm:FermatsLastTheorem}
    No three positive integers \(a\), \(b\) and \(c\) satisfy the equation \(a^{n} + b^{n} = c^{n}\) for any integer greater than two.
\end{myTheorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The fact that the answer I link to achieves so much more than this one may give you an idea of what it possible. Note that the answer I link to answers a question in which the user provided an MWE, such questions tend to get received better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That would definitely work. I didn't provide any MWE because I had no idea that an example like the one in the link you passed me could be adapted to my needs. This is the first time I heard of tcolorbox.

Comment: How to make it work with `breakable`?

Comment: Can one achieve something similar for mdframed in `declaretheoremstyle` declarations?